# Python, Regex: non-greedy not working when overlapping?

Tags: python, regex, overlapping, non-greedy

**MCVE python snippet**

```
import re
str = "aa {bb cc {dd} ee"
print(re.search("{.*}", str).group())
print(re.search("{.*?}", str).group())
```

**Output is**

```
{bb cc {dd}
{bb cc {dd}
```

**However, I would have expected**

```
{bb cc {dd}
{dd}
```

Why doesn't the additional `?` make the Regex non-greedy? Has the overlapping something to do with this?

Comment: print(re.search(r'{.*?({.*?})', str).group(1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is non-greedy, but non-greedy doesn't mean, "find the smallest thing that matches," it means, "find the smallest thing that matches starting from the first place in the string that has a match."  The first open curly brace is the start of a match, and the smallest thing that matches from there is `{bb cc {dd}`.